# A remark on cyclic projections in von Neumann algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be  a von Neumann algebra in $B(H)$. Let $x$ be  a positive element in $M$ and $\zeta\in \ker x^{\perp}$.

Q. True or false:  $\zeta\in \overline{Mx\zeta}$ ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is invertible, then the statement is clearly true.  If $x$ is left-pseudo-invertible (i.e. there is an $y \in M$ with $yx=r(x^*)$), the the statement is true as well.  In general, however, operators are not even pseudo-invertible.  We can, however, approximate the pseudo inverse of positive elements.  Thus, we first split $x$ using polar decomposition in a positive operator and a partial isometry. Then we see that the approximate pseudo inverse does the trick.

1. By Polar decomposition $x = v \sqrt{x^*x}$ for some $v \in M$ with $vv^*=r(x)$ and $v^*v=r(x^*)$.  See e.g. [2, p.15].
2. With the Spectral Theorem we can find a sequence $a_i$ of positive operators that commute with $x^*x$ such that $\mathrm{uwlim}_i\  x^*x a_i = r(x^*x)$. See e.g. [1, proof Prop. 6].  (Recall $y_i \to y$ ultraweakly if for all normal states $\varphi$ we have $\varphi(y_i) \rightarrow \varphi(y)$.)
3. Consequently $
   x^* v \sqrt{a_i}^* \sqrt{a_i}v^* x
   = \sqrt{x^*x} v^*v a_i v^*v \sqrt{x^*x}
   = \sqrt{x^*x}  a_i  \sqrt{x^*x}
   = x^*x  a_i$ which converges ultra weakly to $r(x^*x)=r(x^*)$.
4. Thus $\sqrt{a_i}v^* x$ converges ultrastrongly to $r(x^*)$.  (Recall $y_i \rightarrow y$ ultrastrongly if for all normal states $\varphi$ we have $\sqrt{\varphi(y_i^*y_i)} \rightarrow \sqrt{\varphi(y^*y)}$.)
5. Hence $\sqrt{a_i}v^* x - r(x^*)$ converges ultrastrongly to 0. As $\langle (\ )\zeta, \zeta\rangle$ is a normal state, we find
   $\bigl< \bigl(\sqrt{a_i}v^* x - r(x^*)\bigr)^*\bigl(\sqrt{a_i}v^* x - r(x^*)\bigr) \zeta, \zeta \bigr>^{1/2} \rightarrow 0$, which says $\|(\sqrt{a_i}v^* x - r(x^*))\zeta\| \rightarrow 0$.
6. Thus $r(x^*) \zeta$ converges to $\sqrt{a_i}v^* x\zeta$
   and so $r(x^*)\zeta \in \overline{Mx\zeta}$.
7. Finally, note $\zeta \in (\ker x)^\perp = \overline{\mathrm{ran}\ x^*}$ and so $\zeta = r(x^*)\zeta \in \overline{Mx\zeta}$, as desired.

[1] "A universal property for sequential measurement" Westerbaan & Westerbaan (2016, Journal of Mathematical Physics) http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jmp/57/9/10.1063/1.4961526
[2] "Lectures on von Neumann algebras" Topping

Comment: Nice! $\ \ \ \ $

Comment: No problem.  I'm curious: for what do you need the statement?

Comment: Dear  westerbaan, Thanks again for your response. Actually, based on your answer, one may show (easily) that the Theorem 7.2.1 in the book  "Fundamental of the theory ... written by Kadison and Ringrose page 465" gives an equivalent condition for cyclic Von Neuamnn algebras.